# Change gcloud remote user directory

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud

How do I change the home directory to which gcloud copies files. I'm using the following command to copy a file from a local Windows account to Ubuntu which is hosted in a Google Compute Engine instance.

```
gcloud compute copy-files readme.md compute-engine-instance:readme.md
```

For some crazy reason the readme file will end up in a remote home directory with the same name as my local user account. I would like to specify which home directory on the compute engine to copy that file to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gcloud compute copy-files` and other SSH-related commands default to using the name of the local user as the username on the remote host (note that this is very similar to the behavior of plain `ssh`).

Try `gcloud compute copy-files readme.md otheruser@compute-engine-instance:` instead.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in gcloud compute copy-files --help, the command has the following specification:

```
gcloud compute copy-files [[USER@]INSTANCE:]SRC [[[USER@]INSTANCE:]SRC ...]
    [[USER@]INSTANCE:]DEST [--dry-run] [--plain]
    [--ssh-key-file SSH_KEY_FILE] [--zone ZONE] [GLOBAL-FLAG ...]
```

You can specify either a user, or a full path to do what you want.

```
gcloud compute copy-files readme.md user@compute-engine-instance:readme.md
```

or

```
gcloud compute copy-files readme.md compute-engine-instance:/home/user/readme.md
```

The destination can also be a directory. So these would work as well.

```
gcloud compute copy-files readme.md user@compute-engine-instance:~
```

or

```
gcloud compute copy-files readme.md compute-engine-instance:/home/user
```